# How to listen to https endpoint with Yew & Trunk?

Tags: rust, yew, trunk-rs

I am trying to develop a web app, for oauth2 debugging I am required to have the web app respond to https, how can this be done developing with Yew?

Currently I am using:

```
trunk serve --proxy-backend=<backend-endpoint>
```

In order to serve.

Comment: You could use tunnelling with something like `ngrok`

Comment: @NjugunaMureithi Thanks a lot! That was of great help and made me get past my issue! I'd like to give you the credit that you deserve if you could make that into an answer.

Comment: Sure @Nae Let me do that.

Answer (score 1):

You can use tunnelling through a HTTP tunnel which opens your dev server to the internet and has https.
I can recommend you use `Ngrok` but there are way more services out there. Eg:

```
ngrok http 8080
```

You can combine it with something like `cargo-make` to add a new command.

```rust
use ngrok;

fn main() -> std::io::Result<()> {
    let tunnel = ngrok::builder()
        .http()
        .port(8080)
        .run()?;

    let public_url: url::Url = tunnel.http()?;

    Command::new("trunk")
            .arg("serve")
            .arg(format!("--proxy-backend={public_url}"))
            .output()
            .expect("failed to execute process")

    Ok(())
}
```

Comment: Hm, I've actually just kept serving with trunk and ran `ngrok http 8080` it just reflected it to https. Which was fine.

Comment: This was if you want to customise it.

Comment: Thank you, however I was not able to make it work through this. Perhaps I'll edit my question to include a [mcve].